# NSPredicate use in iOS

Tags: iphone, objective-c, nspredicate

Can anyone knows how to use NSPredicate for below format?

> [Any letter][Any Number][Any letter][space][Any Number][Any letter][Any Number]

I want to validate string fot above fromat.

Thanks.

Comment: Does NSPredicate support regular expressions (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Regular_expression)?

Answer (score 3):

Use this format.

```
NSString *str1 = @"a8D 9k3";
NSString *str2 = @"a8 9k3";
NSString *testFormat = @"[a-zA-z][0-9][a-zA-z] [0-9][a-zA-z][0-9]";
NSPredicate *predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"SELF matches %@", testFormat];
```

Following is **valid**:

```
BOOL isValid = [predicate evaluateWithObject:str1];
```

Following is **invalid**:

```
BOOL isValid = [predicate evaluateWithObject:str2];
```

Answer (score 0):

```
NSPredicate *pred = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"SELF MATCHES[c] %@", @"[a-z][0-9][a-z] [0-9][a-z][0-9]"];

if ([pred evaluateWithObject:@"a3B 5C9"])
{
    NSLog(@"It matches!");
}
```